# How to align image in excel

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, interop

I use following code to insert image in excel cell but result is not as excpected

```
bitmap[] ImageArray = GetImageArray();
bitmap currvalue = null;
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(ImageArray[0], true);
currvalue = ImageArray[0];

currentRange.Cells.HorizontalAlignment =Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenterAcrossSelection; 
currentRange.Cells.VerticalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

excelWorkSheet.Paste(currentRange.Cells, currvalue);
excelWorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit();
```

[this is output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiNuc.png)

I cannot use objSheet.Shapes.AddPicture();

I want image center aligned

Comment: To vertical allign the picture use: Excel.XlVAlign instead of Excel.XlHAlign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be necessary to adjust the position of the image in the cell by code, after it was pasted to excel seheet. Something like the following, HTH

```
excelWorkSheet.Paste(currentRange.Cells, currvalue);

foreach (var shp in excelWorkSheet.Shapes)
{
    if (shp.TopLeftCell.Address != currentRange.Address)
        continue;
    shp.Left = shp.TopLeftCell.Left + (shp.TopLeftCell.Width - shp.Width) / 2;
    shp.Top = shp.TopLeftCell.Top + (shp.TopLeftCell.Height - shp.Height) / 2;
    break;
 }
```

Comment: Sir but there are some issues when column size is not big enough then image align is disturbed and looks bad then previous

Comment: If the image is to big, then we could try to resize the column before pasting?

Comment: i use excelWorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit();